# R.V. X and Y have joint density $f(x, y) = e^{(-x-y)}$, find $P(X+Y\leq 1)$

Tags: probability-theory

What I did was let $Z = X + Y$ and then did a double integral, where $x$ is integrated from $0$ to $1$ and $y$ is integrated from $0$ to $Z - X$, but that gave me $$-e^{-z} - e^{-1} +1$$ which is not correct, so what would be a different way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X + Y \le 1) = \iint_{x + y \le 1} e^{-(x + y)}\,dx\,dy = 
\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} e^{-y} e^{-x}\, dy\,dx$$

Comment: oh, great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$, we know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. You can find the joint PDF of $Z=X+Y$ by convolving the distributions. Ask me if you want to see the work. The resulting distribution is $ze^{-z}$. Then you just need to evaluate:

$$\int_0^1 ze^{-z} dz$$

which can be done with integration by parts. The result is:
$$1-\frac{2}{e}$$.